# std::accumulate is rounding to an integer

Tags: c++

I have the following code which returns me the sum of the last `count` elements in a vector of doubles `foo`:

```
return std::accumulate(foo.rbegin().base() - std::min(count, foo.size()), foo.rbegin().base(), 0);
```

But it is ignoring any decimal part. Why?

Comment: Because 0 is an integer.

Comment: Because you use `0` as the last parameter, which is of type `int`; and this deduces `T = int`.

Comment: `.rbegin().base()` is a very obtuse way of saying `.end()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's surprisingly simple.

The type of the final parameter sets the type of the return of `std::accumulate`.

The simplest thing to do is use 0.0 in place of your final 0:

`return std::accumulate(foo.rbegin().base() - std::min(count, foo.size()), foo.rbegin().base(), 0.0);`

Comment: If you often use accumulate with 0 as last argument, you can also define your own wrapper that calls accumulate with a 0 of the right type.

Comment: I don't like this solution very much, because it (very silently) assumes the value type of `foo` to be `double`. If the value type of `foo` is changed in the future, you have almost no chance to fix this line of code accordingly. It may not be very critical with `float` vs. `double`, though.

Comment: Determining "the right type" was non-trivial when I tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139083/sfinae-check-for-operator

Comment: Indeed @leemes.  I upvoted your answer. My answer is a cheat in the sense that I work with the OP on mathematical / scientific code and so I know his codebase. Using 0.0 is quite idiomatic in such code.

Answer (score 3):

Because you use `0` as the last parameter (the "initial value"), which is of type `int`; and this deduces `T = int`. (*)

I recommend to use `foo.value_type()` as the last parameter. This evaluates to zero for primitive types such as `int`, `float`, `double`, etc.

You can wrap this in a function template `accumulate_zero` to save some redundant work if needed often. The following function template implements this by setting `T` to the value type of the passed iterator:

```
template<class InputIt,
         class BinaryOperation,
         class T = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
T accumulate_zero(InputIt first, InputIt last, BinaryOperation op)
{
    return std::accumulate(first, last, T(), op);
    //                                  ^^^
}
```

---

<sup>(*) That's simply how type deduction works. `std::accumulate` is a function template with, among others, the type `T` being a template parameter. If not given explicitly and if possible, it is deduced from the passed argument's type.</sup>