# How can both a bool and its not value be false?

Tags: c++, templates

While attempting to solve [this (un)problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998793/sfinae-to-have-a-class-member-only-if-possible), I noticed a very strange behaviour which in short made possible that a `bool` is false and its `!` (not value) is also false. I would like to know how this is possible. The code that causes this follows:

```
template<typename T, typename TID = unsigned int>
struct AId {
  typedef AId<T, TID> type;
  typedef T handled_type;
  typedef TID value_type;

private:
  value_type id;

  template<typename _T> struct IsIncrementable
  {
    template<typename _U> using rm_ref = typename std::remove_reference<_U>::type;
    typedef char (&yes)[1];
    typedef char (&no)[2];
    template<class _U>
    static yes test(_U *data, typename std::enable_if<
                      std::is_same<_U, rm_ref<decltype(++(*data))>>::value
                    >::type * = 0);
    static no test(...);
    static const bool value = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test((rm_ref<_T> *)0));
  };

public:
  explicit AId(const value_type &id) : id(id) {}

...

  //IsIncrementable<value_type>::value is false:
  //error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
  template<typename std::enable_if<IsIncrementable<value_type>::value, int>::type = 0>
  type operator++(int /*postfix*/) { type old(id); ++id; return old; }

  //!IsIncrementable<value_type>::value is also false:
  //error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
  template<typename std::enable_if<!IsIncrementable<value_type>::value, int>::type = 0>
  type operator++(int /*postfix*/) { type old(id); ++id; return old; }
};
```

How is it possible that `IsIncrementable<value_type>::value` is false and `!IsIncrementable<value_type>::value` is also false?

Comment: See the comment in the code, the error I get is enable_if<false, ..> in both, so arguments to both enable_if are false.

Comment: Looking at this, Barry's answer even solves the problem you referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998793/sfinae-to-have-a-class-member-only-if-possible), with a simpler answer than mine.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot so it also doesn't give false positives for other SFINAE uses? (not so fun fact: I have already used similar code before, but dropped it in favor of a different approach and no longer have it)

Comment: Exactly. No false positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably unfair to other members, as the problem doesn't lie within the code of the template, but rather with the instantiations.

@Barry's answear explains why SFINAE wouldn't work here, giving hard errors instead. But if I replace the functions with:

```
  static_assert(IsIncrementable<value_type>::value, "It cannot be incrementable");
  static_assert(!IsIncrementable<value_type>::value, "It has to be incrementable");
```

I still get errors in both assertions. The problem is that I was instantiating the template with two different classes. For one case `IsIncrementable<value_type>::value` was `true` and for the other `IsIncrementable<value_type>::value` was `false`. Since the error would show up on `false`, this gave me the impression that it was always false, even its `!` value.

Answer (score 4):

SFINAE only applies in the **immediate context** of template instantiation. Here's a shorter example:

```
template <class T>
struct X {
    template <std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, int> = 0>
    void foo() {
    }
};
```

`T` is already known by the time `foo` is instantiated, so it isn't a failure that happens during substitution for that function template. It's a hard error. You can't even instantiate `X<int>` because `enable_if_t<false, int>` is already ill-formed, regardless of whether or not you call `foo`.

You'll have to introduce a defaulted type parameter that would actually fall into the immediate context:

```
template <class T>
struct X {
    template <class U=T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>::value, int> = 0>
    void foo() {
    }
};
```

Now, SFINAE-ing on `U` is fine - `U` is a template parameter local to this function so that instantiation will be delayed until *this function* is used. So `X<int>{}` is fine and `X<int>{}.foo()` will fail because overload resolution fails to find a viable overload - this `foo()` was just removed.

Comment: While this is a nice explanation on why SFINAE wouldn't work in my code, it does not answear the question of how can a bool value be false and its `!` also be false. If I change the code the functions to

Comment: (forgot shift before enter, can't edit comment)
  `static_assert(IsIncrementable<value_type>::value, "It cannot be incrementable");
  `static_assert(!IsIncrementable<value_type>::value, "It has to be incrementable");`
it still doesn't compile. I now realize I should've chosen this exposition instead of the functions.

Comment: @Olivetree The answer to the question is that SFINAE doesn't work in your code, so whichever one is `false` is hard error. It's not that the bool is a both true and false simultaneously.

Comment: But that's exactly my problem: they both show up with the same error: std::enable_if<false,void> has no type. Meanwhile I have figured my exact problem and will post an answear.

Comment: @Barry: and s/type/time/ in that sentence?  Or am I just failing to parse?